# Run multiple SQL files in MySQL located in a folder tree

Tags: mysql, bash

I have a folder structure with multiple SQL files each.

I would like to know how to run all source files with MySQL massively from the shell. I use Ubuntu.

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

```
sql
    admin
        adm_a.sql
        adm_b.sql
        adm_c.sql
    user
        usr_new.sql
        usr_upd.sql
    operator
        opr_ctrl.sql
        opr_migrate.sql
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Thank you all for your responses, I could finally get:**

```
for i in `find . -name "*.sql"`; 
do mysql -e "source `expr ${i:2}`" -u MyUser -pMyPassword MyDataBase; 
done
```

I hope this will serve somebody.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do your research to get the exact commands for your shell type, but on a high-level this what you need  to do in your script:

```
connect to mysql (with username/password)
for subfolder in `sql`:
    sql_files = list(*.sql)
    for sql_file in sql_files:
        pipe sql_file to mysql db
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

Not exact commands but something like this will work

```
for directory in admin user operator
do
  for sql_file in directory/*.sql
  do
     mysql db_name < sql_file.sql
  done
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution.